# Multiple github private npm repositories on a server

Tags: node.js, github, ssh, npm

I have a node application on github in a private repository. This node application also has custom modules that I made and they are in a separate private repository.

This is the example node application url:

```
git@github.com:thomas/node-application.git
```

These are both node modules that node application uses.

```
git@github.com:thomas/node-module1.git
git@github.com:thomas/node-module2.git
```

You can use the following to install a private npm module on github.

```
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:thomas/node_module1.git
```

In order for this to work the machine needs to have ssh keys setup.

My local machine has my github user keys set up and access to all my repos.

On my server, however I'm using deploy keys. The only way I know how to use multiple deploy keys is as follows.

```
Host na.github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gh_node-application
ForwardAgent yes

Host nm1.github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gh_node-module1
ForwardAgent yes

Host nm2.github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gh_node-module2
ForwardAgent yes
```

So I'd need to install the modules on the server with

```
npm install git+ssh://git@nm1.github.com:thomas/node_module1.git
                          ^^^
```

Which means that the production and development dependancies would be different

```
"node-module": "git+ssh://git@github.com:thomas/node-module1.git"
```

vs

```
"node-module": "git+ssh://git@nm1.github.com:thomas/node-module1.git"
                              ^^^
```

---

This could work if I could do something like this…

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gh_node-application
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gh_node-module1
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gh_node-module2
ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: I went the route of [Machine Users](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys). Which I really hate XD

Comment: Have you tried adding your deploy keys to your github account? All keys added to your account will allow you to access your private packages. This solution is effective only if don't have too many keys, and they don't keep changing too frequent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the server SSH access to your private github repos using Deploy Keys.

https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Node.js Documentation on loading modules from the global directory or a different path.

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders